# Rails tab selection

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have a tab-like button interface to interact with my site using the following HTML

```
<li class="current_page_item"><a href="/home" class="first">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/projects">Projects</a></li>
<li><a href="/resume">Resume</a></li>
<li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
```

The `class="current_page_item` attribute changes the look of the tab. Each url is a view managed my my StaticPages controller, how can I make each view have its respective 'tab' selected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`current_page?(url)` method can help you.

Create an additional helper method.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  #...
  def tab_item(name, url)
    opts = {}
    opts[:class] = 'current_page_item' if current_page?(url)
    content_tag :li, opts do
      link_to name, url
    end
  end
  #...
end
```

And use it in your view

```
<%= tab_item 'Home', root_path %>
<%= tab_item 'Projects', projects_path %>
<%= tab_item 'Resume', resume_path %>
<%= tab_item 'Contact', contact_path %>
```

Comment: This only works if you only want tabs on the root pages of each section.  If you have any sub-pages within "Projects", it won't match the current page and won't 'activate' the tab.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `before_filter` in your controller with a method for `set_current_tab`:

```
def set_current_tab
  @current_tab = "Projects"
end
```

You can then check this var in your views and display the tab if `@current_tab` is equal to the current tab line item.

Comment: If there are different tabs in the same controller, you can just call that method from each necessary controller method and you can add an argument that accepts the current tab as a string.

Comment: You shouldn't set your instance variables in the view.  The view can check the values of ivars and respond accordingly, but the setting and method calling belongs in the controller.